# How do we get this $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7vfJ0PnB-v4&t=235), $f_{\Theta}(\theta)$ is said to be:

$$f_{\Theta}(\theta) = c\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}\theta^2}$$

[image: img]

I don't quite get that comes from.  Can someone enlighten me?  TIA!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be mentioned explicitly, but this is a *prior*, i.e. a distribution that we *assume* for the parameter before taking account for the data. The lecturer assumed this distribution to de normal, but someone else, or in some other context, could assume a different prior.

Comment: Thank you!!!  That really helps.